# Android debugging not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I have tried everything and the Android debugging still will not work. On my phone it says "Waiting for Debugger" in a alert box but when I try to attach the debugger it does not allow me. I can receive logcat messages but cannot look at cpu usage and memory usage. I also have tried to use DDMS but that also does not work. [image]  [image]
I have tried the following:

1. I added `debuggable true` to build.gradle
2. I enabled ADB integration
3. Updated Android Studio to latest version
4. Updated SDK Tools to latest version
5. Added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>` to manifest
6. Enabled USB debugging on phone
7. Restarted Android Studio and ran `adb kill-server`
8. Restarted Phone and Computer
9. Tried different USB ports on computer
10. Disabled ADB integration and enabled it multiple times

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: sorry to hear this is happening to you. i've also experienced serious, stubborn adb failures. eventually, i completely uninstalled android studio and the sdk and then reinstalled it all. i know that's extreme, but it worked. afterward, i wished i had just done that in the first place. it would have taken less time. sorry i don't have a better answer for you. good luck.

Comment: Other than 'Error' in the drop down menu (first image), did you try changing it to Verbose? Debug? or Info? And doesn't the log show other messages from running apps in your device?

Comment: @ADimaano It shows logcat but does not show memory usage and other statistics

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact problem and realized that I had disabled the Android NDK Support plugin in Android Studio. Once I enabled it and restarted, I was able to debug my applications again. Hope this helps!

[image: Preferences > Plugins > Android NDK Support]